# Create a loop to collect data from an api and send the data to a Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

To create a looping that checks all data blocks of an API I use the method `for(var i=0;i<result.Stages.length;i++)`, but there is a big problem that I don't know how to get around, this collection model below retrieves the data from the first group of `API` data (*the `API` link is in the full script at the end of the question*):

```
result.Stages[0].Events[0].T1[0].Nm;
result.Stages[0].Events[0].T1[0].ID;
result.Stages[0].Events[0].T2[0].Nm;
result.Stages[0].Events[0].T2[0].ID;
result.Stages[0].Events[0].Trh1;
result.Stages[0].Events[0].Trh2;
result.Stages[0].Events[0].Tr1OR;
result.Stages[0].Events[0].Tr2OR;
```

The problem is to get all the data blocks, it is necessary to change both `Stages` and `Events` as well, I tried to put `Stages[i]` in place of `Stages[0]` and `Events[i]` in place of `Events[0]`. But it only collects some data and delivers error missing a lot to collect.

**I would like help on what changes I should make** (I researched the subject but the obtions if I find I couldn't reproduce a way to solve the problem).

My full script:

```
function TestStackoverflow() {
  var url = 'https://prod-public-api.livescore.com/v1/api/react/date/soccer/20210724/auto';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var data = response.getContentText();
  var result = JSON.parse(data);
    
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Test');
  
  sheet.clear();
  
  for(var i=0;i<result.Stages.length;i++){
    var row = [result.Stages[i].Events[i].T1[0].Nm,result.Stages[i].Events[i].T1[0].ID,result.Stages[i].Events[i].T2[0].Nm,result.Stages[i].Events[i].T2[0].ID,result.Stages[i].Events[1].Trh1,result.Stages[i].Events[i].Trh2,result.Stages[i].Events[i].Tr1OR,result.Stages[i].Events[i].Tr2OR];
    sheet.appendRow(row)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need nested loops as the number of layers of the object. Try this please.

```js
function TestStackoverflow() {
  var url = 'https://prod-public-api.livescore.com/v1/api/react/date/soccer/20210724/auto';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var data = response.getContentText();
  var result = JSON.parse(data);
    
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Test');
  
  sheet.clear();
  
  var arr = [["T1[0].Nm","T1[0].ID","T2[0].Nm","T2[0].ID","Trh1","Trh2","Tr1OR","Tr2OR"]]

  result.Stages.forEach(stg => {
    stg.Events.forEach(evt => {
      arr.push([evt.T1[0].Nm,evt.T1[0].ID,evt.T2[0].Nm,evt.T2[0].ID,evt.Trh1,evt.Trh2,evt.Tr1OR, evt.Tr2OR])
    })
  })

  sheet.getRange(1,1,arr.length,arr[0].length).setValues(arr)
  
}
```

You can do this with two for loops as follows:

```js
for (var i=0;i<result.Stages.length;i++) {
  for(var j=0;j<result.Stages[i].Events.length;j++) {
    arr.push([result.Stages[i].Events[j].T1[0].Nm,result.Stages[i].Events[j].T1[0].ID])
  }
}
```

But **forEach** loop makes things a lot easier.

Please note that I've used `range.setValues()` method instead of `sheet.appendRow()`. That is much faster, you can try and see the difference.

Comment: It's also possible to use the `for...of` syntax ([see MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)), which is my favorite.

Answer (score 0):

Put the url in A1, then put in A2

```
=getStages(A1)
```

Formate columns D and E as :

```
0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

... with some additonnal data

```
function getStages(url){
  var jsonString = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonString).Stages
  var result = []
  result.push(['Sid','Snm','Cnm','Esd','Edf','T1[0].Nm','T1[0].ID','T2[0].Nm','T2[0].ID','Trh1','Trh2','Tr1OR','Tr2OR'])
  data.forEach(function(elem){
    result.push([elem.Sid,elem.Snm,elem.Cnm])
    elem.Events.forEach(function(elem2){
      result.push([,,,elem2.Esd,elem2.Edf,elem2.T1[0].Nm,elem2.T1[0].ID,elem2.T2[0].Nm,elem2.T2[0].ID,elem2.Trh1,elem2.Trh2,elem2.Tr1OR,elem2.Tr2OR])
    })
  })
  return result
}
```